# How to dispose memory of the UIbutton from the UIScrollview in xamarin.ios

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, profiler

**a method used to create a button and added in a scroll view.**

```
for (int i = 0; i < navTiles.Count; i++)
  {
    navTab = navTiles[i];
    tileRow += staticheight + 15;
    contentHeight = tileRow + 15;
    if (navTab.IsFullTile)
    {
      using (var img =   UIImage.FromBundle(navTab.ImageName))
       {
         using (var navButton = new UIButtonCustom())
         {
           navButton.Frame = new CGRect(15, tileRow, ScreenSize.Width - 30, staticheight);
           navButton.SetImage(img, UIControlState.Normal);
           navButton.TouchUpInside += NavButton_TouchUpInside;
           navButton.TouchUpOutside += NavButton_TouchUpOutside;
           navButton.Tag = (int)navTab.NavTabType;
           //var weaks = new WeakReference(navButton);
            svMainScrollView.AddSubview(navButton);
          }
        }
       }
     }
```

**Method used to dispose of the memory from the button**

```
        if (disposing)
        {

            foreach (var obj in this.svMainScrollView.Subviews)
            {

                if (obj.GetType() == typeof(UIButtonCustom))
                {
                    UIButton uIButton = (UIButtonCustom)obj;

                    if (uIButton.Tag == 1 || uIButton.Tag == 2 || uIButton.Tag == 3 || uIButton.Tag == 4 || uIButton.Tag == 5 || uIButton.Tag == 6)
                    {

                        uIButton.TouchUpInside -= NavButton_TouchUpInside;
                        uIButton.Dispose();
                        uIButton.RemoveFromSuperview();
                        uIButton = null;

                        Console.WriteLine("has tag");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("has no tag");
                    }

                }

            }
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);

        }
        base.Dispose(disposing)
       }
```

But still memory not get removed. but increase the count whenever again create a button Xamarin.ios
Please find the attached Xamarin profiler image in that you can find UICustombutton count get increasing and when push view to another view controller
and come back again pushing to new view controller memory count increase in the profiler
Help me out how to avoid the increasing the memory count whenever create a new object

I am using the xamarin profiler enterprise trial version 1.6.4.16 and snapshot capturing working and only live object checkbox not working

please find attached xamarin profiler screenshot[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your dispose method add the following line before calling `uIButton.Dispose()`:

`uIButton.TouchUpOutside -= NavButton.TouchUpOutside;`

As you are adding handlers for both touchupINSIDE and touchupOUTSIDE in the view's creation you need to remove both on disposal to free the references.